# Is there a way to run a task only when a DAG is cleared and run again?

Tags: airflow

In order for a DAG to be idempotent, we want to have a cleanup task run before a data pull task, but only if the data pull task fails and we re-run the entire DAG for that execution date. We don't want to do this cleanup on failure because we might need the evidence to understand what went wrong and we don't want to run it every time because it is computationally expensive.

It seems like there should be a way with a sensor and [the `restarting` state](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/tasks.html#task-instances) or alternatively skip the cleanup task if the DAG is on its first run. Can someone provide an example?

Comment: Is it only failed case? If you run again for the same execution date regardless of success/failure, I am imagining you need cleanup, unless the pull task is deduplicating the data?    

Is it wrong to add a cleanup process in the beginning of pull task so that every time pull task is executed, first cleanup before pulling?

Comment: oh that's a good point. Yeah it would be ideal to do in any retry case. (we're actually currently dealing with some issues where our pipeline is failing silently so we have to clean up and then clear successful dates)
Maybe we should just have the cleanup happen on every task run and that would take less time to implement than any computing savings we get from a more complex solution.